# Data Table distinct value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, .net, data, datatable

[image]

```
dtnew1.DefaultView.Sort = "Modified DESC";
DataTable unique = dtnew1.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

In this code's "unique" table I'm getting all values but post title value is getting repeated. I need a distinct value from post title like:

```
new test 2014-08-02 2  Test              8/2.2014  
test     2014-08-02 2  test testedby a   7/29/2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DataTable unique =dtnew1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row["Posttitle"]).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());
```

Add `System.Data.Linq` reference